# Dissolve Shapefile and sum attribute in R

Tags: python, r, merge

I have a shapefile with thousands of polygons and a separate csv of additional attribute data. I have joined these by

```
new_shp <- merge(old_shp, add_data, by.x="ID", by.y="ID")
```

However, now I want to summarise some attribute fields that have been added by any aggregate function. For instance I want new_shp@data to go from:

```
small_area  large_area    age
    1           A          50
    2           A          40
    5           B          40
```

to:

```
  large_area     avg(age)
    A              45
    B              40
```

with the boundaries now defined by large_area.

Is this possible using R and if not then by any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate()` from `raster` package:

```
shp@data
##   id class age
## 0  1     A 100
## 1  2     A 200
## 2  3     B 300

library(raster)

shp <- aggregate(shp, by = 'class', sums = list(list(mean, 'age')))

shp@data
##   class age
## 1     A 150
## 2     B 300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shp@data 
small_area  large_area    age
    1           A          50
    2           A          40
    5           B          40

library("dplyr")

new_shp<-group_by(shp,large_area)%>%
  summarize( average= mean(age))
```

and you will have

```
 new_shp@data
large_area        age
    A              45
    B              40
```

Comment: This produces the error message:   no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied 
    to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialPolygonsNULL', 'SpatialVector')"